# ng-click not working on second click inside table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using below code inside a table for navigating to a different page, it works fine for first time after ctrl+f5 in browser, but it does not load other page when I click it second time. It shows empty page, I googled, but I could not find anything.

Controller Code:

```
var viewConfig=mod.controller('ConfigCtrl',function($scope, $rootScope, $location, $route, Configuration, $http, $mdDialog, $mdMedia){
   $scope.navToPageB= function(){
     $location.path('/navToPageB');
   }
});

viewConfig.resolve = {
 configuration: function(Configuration, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    Configuration.query(function(successData) {
        deferred.resolve(successData);
    }, function(errorData) {
        deferred.reject();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
 },
delay: function($q, $defer) {
    var delay = $q.defer();
    $defer(delay.resolve, 1000);
    return delay.promise;
}
}
```

Html page:

```
<a href="">
    <button ng-click = "navToPageB()">Navigate</button>
</a>
```

Any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be nice to see your controller.

Comment: what are you using ngroute or ui routing?? The answer will depend upon that too. Plus would be easier to help if you could share how you are actually navigating in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$route.reload()` after you have redirected to other view for the first time.

Do let me know if this doesnt work and provide the controller code as well.I faced this issue few days back.